# DriverManager.setLoginTimeout does not work in java , what is the alternative solution for this?

Tags: java, mysql

Because, If a host is not reachable It will takes 1 to 2 minutes to throw exeception . I want to reduce the time . So, can anyone should help me to assist .

Answer (score 1):

try

```
java.net.InetAddress.isReachable(int)
```

more on it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29).